# Node.js+Nginx throwing 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed Node.js application to dev environment. Configuration is : 
Ubuntu 16.x
PHP 7.0
Node.js 8.x
Mysql
PhpMyAdmin
Nginx

My node app is using port 2000 and the subfolder name is nodeapp. Though phpmyadmin is opening properly, Node app is giving 502 Bad gateway.

Here is the nginx conf file :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 2000;

    root /home/pjsp/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html app.js;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /nodeapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost/nodeapp:2000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Below is the error I am getting at  /var/log/nginx/error.log file:

```
2018/06/02 13:13:15 [error] 32209#32209: *763 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000
```

Please help!

> Update:

New Config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
        #listen 2000;

    root /home/pjsp/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html app.js;

    server_name app.pajasa.com www.app.pajasa.com;

    location /nodeapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Now getting error :

```
2018/06/02 14:52:35 [alert] 3026#3026: *765 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: app.pajasa.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/nodeapp:2000", host: "www.app.pajasa.com"
```

url : [www.app.pajasa.com/nodeapp:2000](http://www.app.pajasa.com/nodeapp:2000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop inside your nginx. that's why you see:

```
/nodeapp:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000:2000....
```

If your Node app, is listening on port 2000, don't use `listen 2000;` on Nnginx.

And after you drop that, request to: `http://localhost/nodeapp` will be passed onto your node app.

Furthermore, your `proxy_pass` is incorrect, it should be:

```
 proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
```

**UPDATE**

Your URL is **wrong**

```
www.app.pajasa.com/nodeapp:2000 // INCORRECT
```

First of all as we already mention, if you're using Nginx to proxy to your Node.js APP, you don't have to add the port on the URL, secondly and more important is that isn't how ports work:

```
www.app.pajasa.com:2000 // This is correct
```

Drop `:2000` from the URL, Nginx will proxy it to your node app.

```
www.app.pajasa.com/nodeapp
```

Comment: Thanks , I changed according to your suggestion and now Log error is changed to below:
2018/06/02 13:32:46 [alert] 2367#2367: *2293 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: app.pajasa.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/nodeapp:2000", host: "www.app.pajasa.com"

Comment: Thanks .. Did the same now the error is : 
[error] 2476#2476: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 175.100.142.211, server: app.pajasa.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2000/nodeapp:2000", host: "www.app.pajasa.com"

Comment: Sorry, but no, you're not doing it correctly, you're requesting to: `/nodeapp:2000` which is not valid. just request to: `http://localhost/nodeapp` you don't need 2000 anywhere, Nginx will handle port forwarding for you, that's the whole point of using nginx

Comment: Now error is :
 3026#3026: *765 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: app.pajasa.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/nodeapp:2000", host: "www.app.pajasa.com"

Comment: Is your node server running? post full nginx config again, and make sure your app is running: `curl http://localhost:2000` what does it output?

Comment: Your config is **wrong** have you read my answer? `proxy_pass http://localhost:2000`

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_pass http://localhost:2000/nodeapp;`

Your URL scheme is wrong, its always PROTO://DOMAIN:PORT/PATH

Comment: CHanged , But now getting below error:  [alert] 2367#2367: *2293 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: app.pajasa.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/nodeapp:2000", host: "www.app.pajasa.com"

Answer (score -1):

```
    listen 2000;
```

Your nginx should not listen to the app port. In this case the nginx is calling it self recursively.

Comment: Thanks , I commented that and also changed the proxy pass to  proxy_pass http://localhost/nodeapp;
now error is getting change to this :  [alert] 2367#2367: *2293 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: app.pajasa.com, request: "GET /nodeapp:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/nodeapp:2000", host: "www.app.pajasa.com"